# The divs remain invisible after clicking the browser back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I have used `react-router` in `App.jsx` where the parent component is the `Main` component with following Routes

```
<Route path="/" element={<Main />}>
  <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />} />
</Route>
```

In `Main.jsx` I have used `NavLink` on two "Button" components for `Login` and `Signup` to the above respective routes. The Buttons have `handleClick` function which applies a class called `"invisible"` to the two divs mentioned below which sets the display property to none using conditional rendering to hide the divs and only render the `<Outlet />` (`Login` or the `SignUp` component).
But when you try to go to back to the `"/"` route using the browser back button the divs are still invisible and the page need to be reloaded in order for it to be visible.

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Main from "./Main";
import SignUp from "./SignUp";
import Login from "./Login";
import Home from "./Home";
import {  createBrowserRouter, createRoutesFromElements, Route, RouterProvider,} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<Main />}>
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Main.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

function Main() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-div">
      <div className={`main-heading-div ${isVisible ? "" : "invisible"}`}>
        <p className="main-heading">
          Welcome to <span>The Book Keeper</span>
        </p>
        <p>Your Personal Library, Perfectly Organized</p>
      </div>

      <div className={`button-div ${isVisible ? "" : "invisible"}`}>
        <NavLink to="/login">
          <Button text="Log in" name="main-login" onClick={handleClick} />
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/signup">
          <Button text="Sign Up" name="main-signup" onClick={handleClick} />
        </NavLink>
      </div>

      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

This problem arose when I tried to solve a previous problem of, the result of the `<Outlet />` overlapping with with contents of the `Main` component when any of the `NavLink` where clicked. So I tried to solve this by used `useState` + css and then arrived at this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the `isVisible` state back to `true` when the user navigates to the `"/"` root route you could use the [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) and `useEffect` hooks to check for that match explicitly and reset the state.

Example:

```js
import { NavLink, Outlet, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

function Main() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  const homeMatch = useMatch("/");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (homeMatch) {
      setIsVisible(true);
    }
  }, [homeMatch, setIsVisible]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  };

  ...
}
```

Of course, if all you are really trying to accomplish is for the `Main` component content to only be rendered on `"/"` then it might be more advisable to refactor that into an index route component.

Example:

```
const MainPage = () => (
  <>
    <div className="main-heading-div">
      <p className="main-heading">
        Welcome to <span>The Book Keeper</span>
      </p>
      <p>Your Personal Library, Perfectly Organized</p>
    </div>

    <div className="button-div">
      <NavLink to="/login">
        <Button text="Log in" name="main-login" />
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/signup">
        <Button text="Sign Up" name="main-signup" />
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <div className="main-div">
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<Main />}>
      <Route index element={<MainPage />} />
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp />} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

Comment: I first used useMatch and useEffect which did seem to solve the problem at hand, but what i actually wanted to do was what you provided in the second example with the index route component. It helped greatly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NayanKadhre Right... answer the question you asked... then answer the question I believed you were really trying to ask.  Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!